# azure storage commitblocks() results in contentlength '0'?

Tags: node.js, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have divided my file into chunks and trying to upload it to storage account.I am not getting any error but when I see the results of commitblocks() is as following:

```
container:'my-blob-container'
contentLength:'0'
contentSettings:{contentMD5: 'PFfcO0tyGmNOVhXHeQ1xwA=='}
etag:'"0x8D9483395CD3051"'
lastModified:'Fri, 16 Jul 2021 08:27:44 GMT'
list:{blockIds: Array(11)}
name:'6023f6ae3601233c080b1365/spe10_lgr311_2021-02-10_09-08-37/output/216mb.out'
requestId:'f077a104-a01e-006b-521c-7a6035000000'
```

here is the API and my blockid format:

```
const blockIds = request.headers["x-blockids"].split(',');
console.log(blockIds) ////////////(11) ['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10']
var host = sasurl.substring(0, sasurl.lastIndexOf("/"));
var containerName = sasurl.substring(sasurl.lastIndexOf("/"), sasurl.indexOf("?")).split("/")[1];
var saskey = sasurl.substring(sasurl.indexOf("?"), sasurl.length);
var blobService = storage.createBlobServiceWithSas(host, saskey);
blobService.commitBlocks(containerName, pathname, blockIds, function(error, result){
if(error) console.log(error);
console.log( "blocks uploaded",result);
});
```

create block API:

```
const blockId = request.headers["x-block-id"];
console.log(blockId)
const chunkSize = Number(request.headers["x-content-length"]);
const userrole = request.headers["x-userrole"];
const pathname = request.headers["x-pathname"];

var form = new multiparty.Form();
form.parse(request, function (err, fields, files) {
    if (files && files["payload"] && files["payload"].length > 0) {
        var fileContent = fs.readFileSync(files["payload"][0].path);
        console.log('fileContent', fileContent)
        // fs.unlink(files["payload"][0].path, function (err) {
        //     if (err) {
        //         log.error("Error in unlink payload:" + err);
        //     }
        // });
        var size = fileContent.length;
        if (size !== chunkSize) {
            sendBadRequest(response, "Chunk uploading was not completed");
            return;
        }
    genericHandler.getUserSubscMapping().then(function (results) {
        if (results != undefined && results != null) {
            var sasurl = results[0].mapping.find(item => item.name == userrole).sasurl;
            if (sasurl == null) {
                response.status(500).send("Subscription mapping not configured");
                return;
            }
            var host = sasurl.substring(0, sasurl.lastIndexOf("/"));
            var containerName = sasurl.substring(sasurl.lastIndexOf("/"), sasurl.indexOf("?")).split("/")[1];
            var saskey = sasurl.substring(sasurl.indexOf("?"), sasurl.length);
            var blobService = storage.createBlobServiceWithSas(host, saskey);
            //converting chunk[buffers] to readable stream
            //var stream1 = Readable.from(fileContent);
            var data = '';
            var stream = fs.createReadStream(files["payload"][0].path)
            //  console.log('stream',stream);
            stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
                //     console.log('chunk',chunk)
                //    data+=chunk;
                //    console.log('data',data);
                var options = {
                    contentSettings: {
                        contentType: fields['Content-Type']
                    }
                }
                blobService.createBlockFromStream(blockId, containerName, pathname, stream, size, options, (data, error) => {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log("unable to upload", error);
                        response.status(500).send("Blob upload failed");
                        return;
                    }
                    console.log('data111', data)
                });
            });
            stream.on("error", err => console.log('eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee', err));
            stream.on('end', end => console.log('fffffffffffff'));
```

this code is throwing err:
unable to upload:isSuccessful: true,
statusCode: 201,
body: '',
headers: {'content-length': '0',...

Comment: This is expected behavior. The content length is for the response content length of `Put Block List` REST operation which does not return any content.

Comment: but in blob i dont see any content and blob size is 0kb

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the code for uploading blocks as well?

Comment: The blocks are not getting created as here it is showing contentlength 0? Am i passing the correct stream?

Comment: Can you please format your code with proper indentation? It is extremely hard to follow your code. Thanks.

Comment: sure, here it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234967/discussion-between-gaurav-mantri-and-s-d).